# Minor design issue

Tags: bug, design

While browsing the [URI](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team) I noticed a tiny little css bug ( z-index related !?) .I have attached a screen shot with the area highlighted in red.

[image]

Comment: Can confirm, the static side menu needs to scroll up once the footer starts rolling in